# If user is not in /etc/passwd, can he list the contents of a folder?

Tags: permissions, docker, passwd

I am running docker container with `--user <user-id>:<group-id>` option.

The user-id is not in `/etc/passwd`. That is ok. But I want to list the contents a folder.

```
ls /root
```

The root folder has read access to others.

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

Since the user now belongs to "others" category, and since the directory (/root) allows read access to others category, the user should be able to list the contents of the directory.

But when I try to list down the contents of /root, I am getting permission denied error for that user.

The relevant portion of the docker image is shown below:

```
FROM quay.io/centos/centos:8.4.2105 AS base
RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
RUN source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm install 14.17.0
RUN groupadd --gid 10 xyz && usermod -G xyz root && passwd -d root
USER root:10
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l"]
```

I am not able to access /root/.nvm when I run the image with --user `<my-user-id>:<my-group-id>`

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and Docker? Which Docker image, if it's a public one? Is `/root` a volume mounted from elsewhere? What is the output of `namei -lx /root` in the container?

Comment: Please provide moreinformation, what dockerimage ar eyou using? Also, it's a good practice not to use root user for admin related activities unless you really have to and know what you're doing. What are the permissions on the host and on the guest?

Comment: Added more info as requested . /root/.nvm has 755 access but not able to view the contents of the directory. Because others has read access, I will expect the user with no entry in /etc/passwd to be able to read.